# WPF Attached property not working for setting HorizontalAlignment in child elements

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0, attached-properties

In our WPF 4.0 projects (not Silverlight), we are using several custom attached properties to set property values in all children of a container, typically a `Grid` or a `StackPanel`. We prefer this strategy over styles and other alternatives as we can use it with less of a line of code, in the same declaration of the container.

We have a custom attached property for setting several typical properties, like the `Margin` properties of all children of a container. We are experiencing problem with one of them, the `HorizontalAlignment`property. The custom attached property is identical to others:

```
public class HorizontalAlignmentSetter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HorizontalAlignment", typeof(HorizontalAlignment), typeof(HorizontalAlignmentSetter), new UIPropertyMetadata(HorizontalAlignment.Left, HorizontalAlignmentChanged));
    public static HorizontalAlignment GetHorizontalAlignment(DependencyObject obj) { return (HorizontalAlignment)obj.GetValue(HorizontalAlignmentProperty); }
    public static void SetHorizontalAlignment(DependencyObject obj, HorizontalAlignment value) { obj.SetValue(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, value); }

    private static void HorizontalAlignmentChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var panel = sender as Panel;
        if (panel == null) return;
        panel.Loaded += PanelLoaded;
    }

    static void PanelLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var panel = (Panel)sender;
        foreach (var child in panel.Children)
        {
            var fe = child as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe == null) continue;
            fe.HorizontalAlignment = GetHorizontalAlignment(panel);
        }
    }
}
```

An the usage in XAML is also identical:

```
<Grid util:HorizontalAlignmentSetter.HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Label .../>
    <TextBox .../>
</Grid>
```

The attached property is not invoked and thus the property values are not set in the children of the `Grid`. Debugging the application we see the the static property declaration (`public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached...`) is invoked but no other code is invoked, like the `SetHorizontalAlignment(DependencyObject obj...` and thus the callback `private static void HorizontalAlignmentChanged(object sender,...`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the XAML you're setting the property to the default value which will not cause the `PropertyChanged` handler to fire. The boilerplate Get and Set methods will never be called unless you call them from code because properties set in XAML call `GetValue` and `SetValue` directly (as is the case with wrapper properties on a normal DP).

To ensure the change handler is always called when a value is set you could use a `Nullable<HorizontalAlignment>` instead and set the default to `null`.